# Commons Logging - Stdout/Stderr doesn't work at JUnit4 tests

Tags: java, logging, junit, junit4, apache-commons-logging

**Problem:** Logs doesn't echo anything in my unit tests. Logging works well in my app, but when I move the same code to `test` package they stop working. *(see code below)*

**Question:** How to get logs in my unit tests?

**Code:**

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class LogTest {

  private static final Log _LOG = LogFactory.getLog(TransformerServiceTest.class);

  @Test
  public void testLogs() {
    _LOG.info("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"); // NEVER ECHOES TO STDOUT
  }
}
```

**Update: Now only _LOG.error() works**

After changing to DEBUG level, only ERROR level works

*log4j.properties*

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

*LogTest.class*

```
public class LogTest {

    private static Log _LOG = LogFactory.getLog(LogTest.class);

    @Test
    public void test() {
        _LOG.error("Error works!"); //works
        _LOG.warn("Warn works!"); //doesn't work
        _LOG.info("Info works!"); // doesn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: add log configuration to your test.  If you are using a maven build, put log configuration in the src/test/resources directory.

Comment: Maybe show your configuration/build process as well? This isn't really enough information for us to do anything other than guesswork.

Comment: @DwB thanks! I included log4j.properties and it works. But I don't know how to include all levels of logging. Can you suggest how to log INFO, WARN, ERROR?

Comment: @sheltem Do you know how to include all levels of logging. Can you suggest how to log INFO, WARN, ERROR?

Comment: Set the log level to the lowest value (DEBUG or TRACE) and everything at and above it will show.

Comment: @DwB look at updated section of my question pls

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the log4j dependency into your classpath and all will work fine.

If you are using Maven then just add this to the `dependencies` element in the pom.xml:

```
...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
...
```

If you have a simpler working env, just add it to your classpath